# DPM 2012 virtual server stuck backing up

Tags: windows, backup, hyper-v, scdpm

I have a DPM 2012 server which has a virtual server stuck 'Backing up' and cannot be started.  As the virtual server lives on a host with a number of other virtual servers the only way we have fixed this problem in the past is to move all the other virtual servers to another host and then reboot the host with the problem.  This is very time consuming and wondered if there was a way to disconnect or stop the virtual server being backed up.  I have come across a post that says to restart the 'Hyper V Virtual machine management' service but I suspect that this would stop all the other virtual machines on the host.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you stop the 'Hyper V Virtual Machine Management' service it stops the 'Backing up' error and allows the virtual server to be started.  Job Done!